# indent some first-column words in a table using PGFplots

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm trying to indent some of the words in the first column of a table using `PGFplotstable`. I can't figure out any other way to do this other than to put 4 spaces in front of the word. Unfortunately, `pgfplotstable` or latex is stripping away the spaces so the words aren't indented. In the MWE below, see that "cat c" and "cat f" are meant to be indented, but once rendered they are left-aligned.

I found the option `trim cells=true|false`, but turning it off had no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
category, value, value 2
cat a,    1,     7
cat b,    2,     6
    cat c,    3,     5
cat d,    4,     4
cat e,    5,     3
    cat f,    6,     2
cat g,    7,     1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}\datatable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
trim cells=false,
col sep=comma,
columns/category/.style={string type,column type=l}
]{\datatable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\quad` in front of `cat c` (or any other spacing commands `\ ,\;,\qquad` etc.)

Comment: @percusse Hmm.. I can do that if creating the table inline like in the MWE... but I'm actually importing the real data from an external .CSV, so that's not really possible.

Comment: Then how do you put four whitespaces in the real data?

Comment: Do you want to indent every 3rd row by any chance?

Comment: Good question about the four white spaces... I was putting them in the csv, but I guess that's just as ugly as putting \quad in the csv....    And yes, indenting every third row could work, but selecting specific rows would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the style `every row no <index>` to set `before row=\quad` for the desired rows.

If you need to change a large number of rows in the same fashion, you can supply the row numbers as a comma separated list if you first call

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    every row no list/.code 2 args={
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \rownumber in {#1}     {
            \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/table/every row no \rownumber/.append style={#2}}
        }
    }
}
```

to define a new key `every row no list`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
category, value, value 2
cat a,    1,     7
cat b,    2,     6
cat c,    3,     5
cat d,    4,     4
cat e,    5,     3
cat f,    6,     2
cat g,    7,     1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
    every row no list/.code 2 args={
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \rownumber in {#1}     {
            \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/table/every row no \rownumber/.append style={#2}}
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}\datatable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    trim cells=false,
    col sep=comma,
    columns/category/.style={string type,column type=l},
    every row no list={2,5}{before row=\quad}
]{\datatable}


\end{document}
```